# Swap specific text with textfield in list in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm workin on an Angular Project where I output a list of objects in a table. 
Here is  an image: [image]

What I want to achieve, is that when you click on a text, this specific text should be swapped against a textfield, so I can change the text and then save it through a controller.

To be more exact, I know how to add a `ng-click` action to the text, but I'm not sure how to target this specific text for the swap and how to save the input of this specific textfield (assuming the textfield has a `ng-model` bound to it). Maybe I can use the id's of the objects? Or can I assign a controller for each object which handles its logic? What's the best way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: probably a custom directive https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive can help you, btw your question is too broad

Comment: Sorry if the question is too broad. Custom directives look good. Thanks for the link @InvernoMuto .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To swap between label and edit field you can introduce a new variable on the object itself.

I hope the fiddle helps you.

http://jsfiddle.net/8078g9vz/3/

Here I have simply used `showEdit`

Comment: Ah, thats a really nice solution. But how would you add more functionality to the button? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can add a custom method in the controller and grab the clicked button by passing `item` object into it.